# I can't get permission to manage external storage on Android 11

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add an intent to work with external storage files, but the "Settings" class does not contain this permission

```cs
// Android 11
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
{
    try
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
        intent.AddCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
        intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(String.Format("package:%s", Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName)));
        StartActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

[image: how to solve this?]

I hope for your help, thank you in advance

Comment: You always leave catch blocks empty?

Comment: It is unclear which problem you encounter.

Comment: Pleaae dont thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not encountering an error, it is just giving you a warning because this Settings is only available on Android R onwards and you are targeting below that, that's why it is showing Warning. For me it's working perfectly fine. And if it's an error, make sure you imported Settings from the android.provider.Settings.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was just necessary to compile the project using Android 11 =)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Android.Provider.Settings`.

Change:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
```

To:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageAppAllFilesAccessPermission);
```

Comment: it does not find this constant =(